# 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, spynner

Not quite understanding why I am getting this trace error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:/Personal Folders/Andy/Python Projects/Salesforce BZ API/Automated Reports.py", line 15, in <module>
    parse = br.soup("find('div')")
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\spynner\browser.py", line 409, in _get_soup
    return self._html_parser(self.html)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
#from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function
import spynner
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

#Loading up Salesforce

br = spynner.Browser()
#br.debug_level = spynner.DEBUG
br.create_webview()
br.show()
br.set_html_parser("BeautifulSoup")
br.load("https://login.salesforce.com/")
parse = br.soup("find('div')")
print(parse)
br.browse()
br.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're setting the HTML parser to the *string* "BeautifulSoup", not to BeautifulSoup.  I don't have it installed so I can't test whether it works, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be it! Wow, I feel like such an idiot!

Comment: No idiocy involved, only inexperience. :^)  If you can see now what the error message is trying to tell you, then you've won more than you lost in time.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look [here](http://packages.python.org/spynner/), and it seems that `soup` is not a function but a property.

Comment: Forgive my newness to programming and Python in general, but what is the difference and how does one go about using them?

Comment: @Andrew: unfortunately, I'm a python noob as well, running of my knowledge of *other* languages.